# How can I change CSS '@media print' styles in jQuery?

Tags: jquery, printing

I am dynamically setting the offset of an html element where `position: relative`. I use the following code (in pure js but jQuery is ideal for me):

```
document.querySelector('#overlay-marker-report').style.left = Math.floor(cli.getXLocation(period)) + 134 + "px";
```

For print, this offset has to change or things don't align properly. Is there a way to do what I am doing but for print specifically?

Comment: Why not use a print style sheet?

Comment: @DelightedD0D The `left` amount is not a constant. I use a print stylesheet for every other element though.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using [matchMedia](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/matchMedia). If that doesn't suite your needs you can change some CSS property on #overlay-marker-report (e.g. float) and test if @media is print that way.